# How to set a new avatar in Flutter and display it using Firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter

How to set a new avatar in Flutter and display it using Firebase ?

Comment: Are you using FirebaseAuth for your user management? Do you already have Firebase Code in your project? Are you currently using Avatars from LoginProviders like Facebook, Google? Please add more information.

Comment: I am using FirebaseAuth , and I would like to set an avatar in my profile, but I am not able to do so

Answer (score 0):

**Setting an avatar:**
You could use FirebaseStorage to store user avatars. In order to do that I would setup an hierarchical storage structure like */users/{**userID**}/avatar.png* whereas **userID** refers to be UID which Firebase assigned to the users. Uploading the image could be done with both the AdminSDK or using the ClientSDK for Firebase. You could setup a Firebase Rule to ensure each user can only update his own avatar image like this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /users/{userId}/{allPaths=**} {
      allow write: if (request.auth.uid == userId);
    }
  }
}
```

In order to upload the image you could procede as follows in your flutter app:

```dart
File avatarImgFile;
String fbUserId;

  Future uploadImageToFirebase(BuildContext context) async {
    String fileName = basename(avatarImgFile.path);
    StorageReference firebaseStorageRef =
        FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('users/$fbUserId/$fileName');
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(avatarImgFile);
    StorageTaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;
    taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(
          (value) => print("Done: $value"),
        );
  }
```

Then you can use the obtained DownloadURL to display your image e.g. using [CachedNetworkImage](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) or similiar methods.